# Symfony kernel.response listener with authorization checker

Tags: php, symfony, listener

I'm setting up a `kernel.response` event and I want to test whether the user is logged in or not inside it.

Here is my code:

`services.yml`

```
app.kernel.modal_injection:
    class: App\UserBundle\EventListener\ModalListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response }
    arguments:
        - @security.authorization_checker
```

`ModalListener.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;


class ConnectModalListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $securityChecker;

    public function __construct( AuthorizationChecker $securityChecker )
    {
        $this->securityChecker = $securityChecker;
    }

    public function onKernelResponse( FilterResponseEvent $event )
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ( !$event->isMasterRequest() ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( $this->securityChecker->isGranted( 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // CODE HERE


    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => array( 'onKernelResponse', 0 ),
        );
    }
}
```

My problem is that upon checking if user `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBER` I get an error 500 upon serving css and js files on my page (means no js or css on it). Is there a way to charge those? Eventually filter the kernel.response event on those?

Comment: Could you share the exact error message from the Symfony Debugger? Your CSS/JS should always work. They are static files.

Comment: I managed to get my hands on the error: `Internal Server Error | Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException [message] The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token was `null` in the static files, therefore `isGranted` returned an error 500. So I have to run a check before:

```
if ( $this->tokenStorage->getToken() !== null
        && $this->securityChecker->isGranted( 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED' ) ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: But why are your static files served by php? Sounds like a misconfiguration in .htaccess

Comment: @mblaettermann Oh :/ I think I have Symfony's default one. Do you have an example so I could compare? (I'm not very good with `htaccess`)